# I cant play audios with python

Tags: windows, audio, pygame, alsa, python-3.8

I tried with all libraries, now im trying with the mixer of pygame, i have a lot of problems with alsa drivers like:

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such 
file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or 
directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or 
directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5181:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pygame.error: ALSA: Couldn't open audio device: No such file or directory
```

so i tried changing the default driver like it says here https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQUsingSDL#Win32 but now i have this problem in every option

```
pygame.error: Audio target 'winmm' not available
```

i dont know what else can i do, someone can help me?
im on windows btw

Comment: im trying to play audio, .mp3 or .wav but i always have an error

Comment: Please include the section of code that causes the error, and the code where the audio objects are initialised.

Comment: What software versions are you using?  `Audio Target winmm` references the windows `winmm.dll`  file.  Is it available to your program?

Comment: How do you get ALSA to show error messages on a Windows system? Are you using WSL?

Comment: Yes, im using wsl

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was using WSL and I got ALSA drivers errors. I ran the code in windows PowerShell and it worked!